# sennding multipart formdata request

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have this form and it's plain html and css. How do I send a multipart request? I need to send this to my api.

In postman, my api takes form data in the body in this format.

```
company -enter a string here
excelFile - enter excel file here
plan_type-enter a string here
```

I need to append the other two company ahd plan_type from my local storage. 
My concern is how to take file from this form and send api requests.

```html
<form name=”myForm” enctype=”multipart/form-data”>
  <div class="row pt-2 pl-3">
    <div class="col-md-5 p-0">
      <a href="assets/exl/company-employee-email-ID.xlsx" target="_blank"> <img src="assets/images/Policy-doc-without.jpg" style="width: 200px; float: left; height: 80px;box-shadow: 0 3px 6px 0 rgba(0, 150, 11, 0.16);" /></a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-5 pl-0 position-relative bg-upload-file">
      <input type="file" name="file" class="input-file">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="pt-5 text-left pb-4">
    <button class="button--light btn-next">SUBMIT</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: first of all `”` should be `"`

Answer (score 0):

It will give you a `FormData` object when you submit this form. Then append you other variables using `FormData.append('VARIABLE_NAME', VALUE)`.

Answer (score 0):

```
<form action="myform" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <div class="row pt-2 pl-3">
            <div class="col-md-5 p-0">
              <a href="assets/exl/company-employee-email-ID.xlsx" target="_blank" >  <img src="assets/images/Policy-doc-without.jpg" style="width: 200px;
                float: left;
                height: 80px;box-shadow: 0 3px 6px 0 rgba(0, 150, 11, 0.16);" /></a>
            </div>
            <div>
                <label for="company_id">Company</label>
          <input type="text" name="company " id="company _id">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-5 pl-0 position-relative bg-upload-file">
                <label for="file_id">Upload File</label>
              <input type="file" name="file" id="file_id" class="input-file">
          </div>
          <label for="plane_type_id">Plane Text</label>
          <input type="text" name="plane_type" id="plane_type_id">
        </div>

      <div class="pt-5 text-left pb-4">
        <button type="submit" class="button--light btn-next">SUBMIT</button> 
      </div>
    </form>
```

It takes 3 parameters Company,file upload ,plane text and sended to myform.
I hope it works for you

Comment: name="file" => name="excelFile" And a bit of explanation won't hurt.

Comment: hey i already have plan_type and company name saved in local storage .

Comment: @gaurag shmara where do i hit the api ?

Comment: then if you no need to take input from user you can retrieve the data in span tag with some id that data also go with file upload.